# A record of deposits for Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution, record-keeping

Years ago I contributed to two Roth IRAs.  At some point I combined them into one.  I am now trying to determine how much in total I contributed to Roth IRAs over those years, but alas, my paperwork is incomplete.

Does the IRS keep a record of Roth IRA deposits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who keeps track of my contributions to my Roth IRA?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/7409/9090)